# Add elements to List in razor ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have declared a `List<string>` in my View as:

```
@{
    List<string> deletedImages = new List<string>();
}
```

I have this anchor tag:
`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Remove(@item, this)">X</a>`

And the script tag:

```
<script>
    function Remove(id, e)
    {
        @deletedImages.Add(id);
    }
</script>
```

I'm getting an error in `@deletedImages.Add(id);` that says:
`The name` id` does not exist in the current context.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The parameter `id` is in javascript context, and the code after `@` is in c# context, you can't do that there. That's not the way to do that, instead, try to create and populate your javascript object, then post it to the controller.

Comment: @SᴇM Yes that's what I want to do, but first I have to populate it in the script tag.

Comment: Correct, but you are trying to populate into c# object.

Comment: @SᴇM nvm I did it. Just created an array inside the script tag